# custom post type query causing errors

Tags: theme-development

Any idea what is wrong with this? It "works" but it runs the error_log bananas. It should be noted that this code excerpt is from the "404.php" file

Here's the code:

```
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <h3 class="heading">Service Areas</h3>
                        <?php
                        $allCities_args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'local',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order'   => 'ASC'
                        );

                        $all_cities = new WP_Query($allCities_args);
                        ?>
                        <div class="nearby_cities ">
                            <?php

                            if ($all_cities->have_posts()) {
                                while ($all_cities->have_posts()) {
                                    $all_cities->the_post();
                                    $city_id = get_the_ID();
                                    $state_check = get_post_ancestors($post_id);
                                    $parent_id = $state_check[0];
                                    if ($parent_id !== 0) {
                                        $nbcities = get_the_title();
                            ?>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="nearby-city" data-parentid="<?php echo $parent_id; ?>"><?php echo $nbcities; ?></a>
                                        </div>
                            <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

Here's not even a fraction of what the error_log is throwing at me (note that the time discrepancies are because I had to get rid of a lot of it to comply with the 30000 character limit):

```
[23-Apr-2022 18:09:09 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:09:09 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:09:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:09:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/types-of-jobs.php on line 93
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:11:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:14:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:14:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:14:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:15:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:15:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:16:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:16:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 482
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 222
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
[23-Apr-2022 18:22:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post_id in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 221
```

Comment: The `get_post_ancestors` need the id of current post as the argument , and you are passing `$post_id` which is not set it should be replaced with `$city_id` in you code which actually is the id of current post (  get_the_ID() ) .

Comment: So what would the corrected code look like?

Comment: `$state_check = get_post_ancestors($city_id);`  . Correct this and check again . If you have any plugins installed Deactivate them and try .

Comment: Ok.... That's MUCH better, I'm not getting AS MANY errors in the error_log now BUT I'm still getting the following errors:
[25-Apr-2022 13:47:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/404.php on line 222
[25-Apr-2022 13:47:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /home/wastere1/staging.wasteremovalusa.com/wp-content/themes/wasteremovalusa/functions.php on line 456

Comment: Did you tried deactivating all the plugins ?  And are you sure that you have content with CPT `local`  ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by content with CPT local

Comment: What does it mean by `'post_type' => 'local',` this line ?  You are trying to query a custom post type (CPT) with the name " local" .

Comment: Yes:
                            $allCities_args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'local',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'orderby' => 'title',
                                'order'   => 'ASC'
                            );

Comment: @AnoopD what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you tried deactivating all the plugins  ?